# gridview delete event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has and auto- generated delete button. The grid has one datakeyname  and for some reason it I am getting this error : Message: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

I have looked at many tutorials and examples. This code should work right?

```
protected void grdBins_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    int rec_id = int.Parse(grdBins.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "delete from t_run_schedule_lots  " +
                       "where rec_id = @id";

     cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rec_id ;

     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Connection = this.sqlConnection1;
     this.sqlConnection1.Open();
     //execute insert statement
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     this.sqlConnection1.Close();
     //re-populate grid */
    fill_grid();
     grdBins.EditIndex = -1;
     grdBins.DataBind(); 
     // this bit was just to see if I was capturing the ID field properly. 
    lblBins.Visible = true;
     lblBins.Text = rec_id.ToString();
}
```

If anyone knows a good example in C# that would make this work it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: nothing come up in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to get it working:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdBins.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Label id = (Label)row.FindControl("Label9");

             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
             cmd.CommandText = "delete from t_run_schedule_lots  " +
                               "where rec_id = @id";

             cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(id.Text) ;
```

Although I don't know why the RowIndex option would not work. Anyway it is working now.

Comment: I just tried your code and I get that index is out of range. It may be bonkers but it works. The selectedIndex is set to -1. I have no idea why this isn't working. Plus your first line of code throws and error if you don't ad .ToString(). Plus I am just learning how to program grids by hand and not use the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the  `DataKeyNames="rec_id"` in the gridview aspx set?
cant get to datakeys if you haven't let the page know what they are

this is a refactored version of your code.

```
protected void grdBins_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
       int rec_id = int.Parse(grdBins.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
            conn.Open();
            string cmdText = @"delete from t_run_schedule_lots
                               where rec_id = @id";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn)){
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rec_id);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
       }
       grd.EditIndex = -1;
       fill_grid();
       grdBins.DataBind(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question but according to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the EditIndex property is zero-based so you can't set it to -1. Setting it to that value will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: That is what I though but It works in the rowupdating event. I have set the index to 1 with the same result.

Comment: I thought that was too obvious :-). What line is actually throwing the exception?